# Table valign content

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a row, with a cell, which contains a input box and an image (*captcha* system).

The image causes the cell to increase in height and as such the input box in no longer inline with its label in the previous cell to the left.

I have tried vertical alignment and *valign* but neither have worked.

whats the solution?

Comment: write it on jsfiddle and send us the link we will help you, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I managed to get what i wanted with some absolute:position rather. tnks guys

Answer (score 0):

try `vertical-align:`

Like so:

`style="vertical-align:bottom"`

See my [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ndVE/1/)